# Filter options "Newest" and "Added" in Saves seem counter-intuitive

Tags: discussion, saves

While using the recently saved question/answer, the filter option "Newest" actually refers to the time when the question/answer is created rather than the "newest question" I, as a user, added to my "Saves" list. And the "Added" option is actually what I'm expecting.

This is so counter-intuitive to a normal user expectation. "Newest" option should be the latest entry to the list (i.e. current "Added" option), as most other Internet sites.

I personally don't find much value from the current "Newest" option where I get to look up Saves for the creation time. I don't care about when it was created, I only want the solution from it, hence, better to name the current "Added" option to "Newest".

Comment: "*I personally don't find much value from the current "Newest" option*" but what if I do?

Comment: @VLAZ If you want to waste time on filtering the question you wanted, then it's your desicion, and have fun doing that. I'm here to propose a better naming for the newest entry, the current "Newest" can be named something else.

Comment: To me, newest matches the rest of the site meaning (when the question was created). Added seems the perfect word for “added to saves”.

Comment: @James Risner In the context of bookmarking, "Added" makes little sense, since the purpose of "Saves" is for user to manage their "question/answer of interest", everything in it is one's "added" collections, so what's the point filtering the thing I added, as everything is of my bookmarkings? It should be more of a user friendly sorting functionality, than a site-coherent placeholder, as it strays from it's purpose.

Comment: This sorting is the same as Followed posts, and I find both sorting options useful. I use saves (bookmarks) for many things (for references, for answering, for moderation, etc.), thus various sorting options are helpful.

Comment: All I can say is I’ve used bookmark/saved “added” sort and I’ve used “newest” sort. Obviously for different reasons. I don’t want either to go away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new Saves feature is great. I'll describe just two ways I make use of **Added** and **Newest**.

I regularly add questions to my Saves, but I may not answer immediately.

My regular use of **Added** is to look at Saves that I have not touched in a while. In an effort to remove them from Saves, answer them, do research in preparation to answer, or refresh the Added time by un-saving/re-saving.

My regular use of **Newest** is to save any recent questions matching my tags, then systematically answer or eliminate them. I could possibly use Added to do this, but it wouldn’t be as precise. Another use is to review older questions regardless of when I added them to Saves.

Comment: I guess I'm not using it correctly, thanks for outlining the details on the use case unmemtioned by others.